# Thread 1 signal sigabrt error when running the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi my app shows no errors, but when I run my app it freezes and shows the THREAD 1 SIGNAL SIGABRT, on the line beginning with 'return'. I am using Xcode 5. Also if I update Xcode to Xcode 6 will this fix the errors?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

   int main(int argc, char * argv[])
   {
     @autoreleasepool {
       return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
      }
   }
```

The debugger shows:

```
   2014-10-18 09:43:14.726 2 Player Pong[448:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception   'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Game 0x8d24a50> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ButtonMove.'
  *** First throw call stack:
   (
   0   CoreFoundation                      0x017ef1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0156e8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
   2   CoreFoundation                      0x0187efe1 -[NSException raise] + 17
   3   Foundation                          0x0122ed9e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
   4   Foundation                          0x0119b1d7 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
   5   Foundation                          0x0119a731 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
   6   Foundation                          0x011fcb0a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
   7   UIKit                               0x004e51f4 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
   8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015807de -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
   9   CoreFoundation                      0x017ea76a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
   10  UIKit                               0x004e3d4d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
   11  UIKit                               0x0034c6f5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
   12  UIKit                               0x0034ce9d -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
   13  UIKit                               0x0034d0d3 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
   14  UIKit                               0x0034d5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
   15  UIKit                               0x0035cf89 -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 36
   16  UIKit                               0x0035d2d1 -[UIViewController _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentationInWindow:fromInterfaceOrientation:] + 297
   17  UIKit                               0x005fb3d5 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:] + 2330
   18  UIKit                               0x003595d5 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 6538
   19  UIKit                               0x00359aef -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
   20  UIKit                               0x00359b2f -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 56
   21  UIKit                               0x007a3e00 -[UIStoryboardModalSegue perform] + 271
   22  UIKit                               0x00792f0c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 174
   23  UIKit                               0x00792f87 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 115
   24  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01580880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
   25  UIKit                               0x002303b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
   26  UIKit                               0x00230345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
   27  UIKit                               0x00331bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
   28  UIKit                               0x00331fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
   29  UIKit                               0x00331243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
   30  UIKit                               0x0026fddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
   31  UIKit                               0x002709d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
   32  UIKit                               0x002425f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
   33  UIKit                               0x0022c353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
   34  CoreFoundation                      0x0177877f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
   35  CoreFoundation                      0x0177810b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
   36  CoreFoundation                      0x017951ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
   37  CoreFoundation                      0x017949d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
   38  CoreFoundation                      0x017947eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
   39  GraphicsServices                    0x037e35ee GSEventRunModal + 192
   40  GraphicsServices                    0x037e342b GSEventRun + 104
   41  UIKit                               0x0022ef9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
   42  2 Player Pong                       0x0000317d main + 141
   43  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e36701 start + 1
   )
   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
   (lldb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have not assigned the key in your VC the key name is **ButtonMove** , go to your attribute inspector remove the invalid key  **ButtonMove** finally clean and run the project

Comment: in your xib or storyboard u created the ButtonMove (as a label, buton, textfiled..), but u r not used means deleted inproperly, just follow my answer,it will be resolved ur problem

Comment: sure my bro my email id is karthik.saral@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

It may be firstly, an outlet referenced to a control which has been removed, secondly, check any wrong Key/value in attribute inspector